# How do I change the color of the space above the website on iOS?

Tags: html, ios, web, safari

[image]

When pulling down at the top of a site in iPadOS it shows a white spot. I have seen sites that change this like dark mode google. I would like to know how to do it **without** changing the background color.

When I try changing the html background it takes the color of the body background

[image]

Comment: I would use `<meta name="theme-color" content="#ecd96f" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#0b3e05" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">` maybe this helps

Comment: This did not work